# Add new lines to suiblist from client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

There is a suitelet where I created a button Search, filter fields and a sublist.
Initially sublist is emtpy. When user enters values to filter fields and clicks Search button it runs a saved search to get filtered transactions. Since function that runs on Search btn click is on Client Script Netsuite returns me this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` when trying to add lines on Sublist.
Here is my suitelet:

```
function onGetRequest(scriptContext) {
    const form = serverWidget.createForm({
        title: 'Suitelet',
    });

    form.clientScriptModulePath =
        '../client/cl_script.js';

    createFilterFields(form);
    createTransactionsSublist(form);
    createButtons(form);

    scriptContext.response.writePage(form);
}

function createTransactionsSublist(form) {
   const sublist = form.addSublist({
      id: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST,
      type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST,
      label: 'Transactions',
   });

   sublist.addField({
      id: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST_TYPE,
      label: 'Type',
      type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
   }).updateDisplayType({
      displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.ENTRY,
   });
}

function createButtons(form) {
    form.addButton({
        id: CUSTPAGE_SEARCH_BUTTON,
        label: 'Search',
        functionName: 'onSearchButtonClick',
    });
}
```

And here is a portion of client script:

```
function onSearchButtonClick() {
    const currRec = currentRecord.get();
    const filterValues = getTransactionSearchFilterValues(currRec);
    const filteredTransactions = getFilteredTransactions(filterValues);

    currRec.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST,
    });
    currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST,
        fieldId: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST_TYPE,
        value: 'Test text',
    });
    currRec.commitLine({
        sublistId: CUSTPAGE_TXNS_SUBLIST,
    });
}
```

According to documentation seems that I am doing this correctly but this still fails.
When I tried to change sublist type to INLINEEDITOR this worked and sublist is being populated. However I need to achieve this with LIST type.
May be there is a way to populate the sublist on suitelet, but I dont know how to pass trasnactions data back to the suitelet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIST` Sublists [have a fixed number of lines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4332704307.html#bridgehead_4332704307); you cannot add or remove lines to a `LIST` via either scripting or the UI.

As you saw, an `INLINEEDITOR` works correctly with your technical approach.

If you must have a `LIST`, you will need to populate the results server-side instead of client-side. You can turn your `Search` button into a SUBMIT button by using `addSubmitButton()` instead of `addButton()` to create it. When clicked, this will submit a `POST` request back to the Suitelet with the values specified in your filter fields populated in the incoming request.

Although I don't recommend the coding style at all (putting all the logic in one entry point function), you can see an example of how to read the field values in [NetSuite's example here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/article_0516043220.html#Create-a-Form-Containing-Several-Field-Types%2C-Reset-and-Submit-Buttons%2C-Tabs%2C-and-a-Sublist).